# Как удалить нажатую инлайн кнопку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

Как удалять конкретно нажатую инлайн кнопку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так.
В целом ответ подходит как для `aiogram` так и для `pytelegrambotapi`, разница минимальная

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, AllowedUpdates


bot = Bot(token="token")
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    # изначальный маркап
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="text1", callback_data="prefix_for_this_markup:text1"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="text2", callback_data="prefix_for_this_markup:text2"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="text3", callback_data="prefix_for_this_markup:text3"),
    )
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="text", reply_markup=markup)


# хендлер для отлова кнопок из маркапа
# работает по префиксу, который вы можете менять как хотите(почти)
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="prefix_for_this_markup:")
async def get_callback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    # всегда отвечаем на колбек
    await call.answer()
    # для телебота
    #bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    # получаем весь маркап у нажатой кнопки
    current_markup = call.message.reply_markup
    # и ищем саму нажатую кнопку по calback_data 
    for row in current_markup['inline_keyboard']:
        for but in row:
            if but.callback_data == call.data:
                # ну и просто удаляем её
                row.remove(but)
    # реадчим сообщение
    await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                        reply_markup=current_markup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, allowed_updates=AllowedUpdates.all())
```

До нажатия
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После нажатия на 1 кнопку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После нажатия на 3 кнопку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]